# Detecting If User Has Signed Out Of Chat

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have made a simple chat application in PHP/Ajax/MySQL.

I am regularly calling these two methods-

```
setInterval("GetChatParticipants()",5000);
setInterval("GetChatMessages()",1000);
```

Now as per client design, there's no Logout or Sign Out button, so I want to detect when user closes the browser and at that time I have to delete the participant record from the database. I dont want to use `onbeforeunload` as Chrome refuses to accept Ajax requests on window unload event.

So I am thinking of implementing in Ajax by making repeated reqests. But the question is how exactly shall I do that. Shall I update the Participant table with `last_active_time` and if the difference between current time and that `last_active_time` is , say, more than 10 min, then I should delete the user? Is it a practical solution or could there be a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the best solution IMO. In Javascript create a "ping" function that pings every minute / two minutes etc with a session ID unique to that browser/session. Have a sessions table on your server and update when you get a ping. Have another script that looks for entries that have not been pinged for long periods and close the sessions.

I've had this structure running for thousands of concurrent users on one site, and I had to  drop the ping down from 1 minute to every 2 minutes when load got heavyish (that was on 2 load balanced servers while running the rest of the site too). Obviously you make your ping approx 45% of the time-out time (so if one fails, a second should hit). It's a simple process that can handle the load.

---

Edit: don't use "setInterval" for the ping, but user "setTimeout" when each ping either returns or fails. Otherwise, with setInterval, if your server gets too loaded then the pings queue, never respond and queue some more. You get a meltdown of the server as all server sockets are used, then you can't connect by ssh to fix it... not a moment I was proud of.

Comment: Additionally, I would still have a sign out / logout function on the server that is being triggered using javascript when the browser closes / the current page is left... There's events for that somewhere. But if they want to do it like Stackoverflow where people stay in the channel for a while after closing so accidental closes of the browser don't impact the chat session, better not :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is practical solution and then only one you can rely on, so, no matter what else you use in addition to that, this one final check should be in your logic at all times. Said that, combining several methods will give you more possibilities to detect user leaving early. Add `onbeforeunload` for browsers that support it. Add "log out" button for clients coming from insecure location that want to log out right now when leaving PC and finally, check for inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is practical solultion. The only difference is where to store information about user ping. You can do it in database or in key-value storage like [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). I prefer the second one as I think it takes lesser resources.